# Running without the SUID sandbox! while running source code for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, open-source, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I download chromium source code and compiled according to the instruction as stated on their website.
Now when I tried to run the binary file for chrom in out/Debug/chrom 
I am getting this error

**[17144:17144:0423/112117:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(169)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.**

my chrome folder is in the /home/user/chromium/src ..

Comment: did you mean `out/Debug/chrome`? Could you fix the typo if any?

Answer (score 4):

Solved this!
when you run out/Debug/chrom and some error like this comes you can run            $**out/Debug/chrom --no-sandbox**

at least the chrome will work then!